# Caller Input Exception: Caller does not have a FPS Caller Account (selfstarter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm still not sure why I am getting the following error: Caller Input Exception: Caller does not have a FPS Caller Account. I've added my AWS keys to my app, and have read through the Amazon FPS guides.

I'd like to get the amazon payments working, I'm using [Self-Starter](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter) as the foundation of my app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar issue recently. The problem was that my AWS account was signed up for FPS, but not the FPS Sandbox. And I was trying out my keys with the sandbox test urls.

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but please make sure that your AWS account is signed up for both the "FPS" service as well as the "FPS Sandbox" (https://payments.amazon.com/help/Amazon-Flexible-Payments-Service/Technical-Resources/Amazon-FPS-Sandbox).

Once you're sure that your AWS account is registered for both, make sure that you change the URLs to the sandbox or production environment appropriately; both when requesting the CBUI pipeline and when performing action of the Amazon Service token.

Hope this helps,

S.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the FPS forum, there have been lots of people with this problem. It appears that it is almost always related to having an account properly set up. In my case, that was also true. If Amazon is lacking any information that they need from you, the account will be inactive and an inactive account also means the sandbox is inactive. I suggest a call to Amazon about your account as that will likely be the only way to address the most likely cause which is an account which has been set up incorrectly either by you or them.

Go here to get an immediate callback:
https://payments.amazon.com/contactusclick2call